# Cannot detect power supply plug/unplug on Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: power-management, battery, gnome-power-manager

After plug/unplug power supply nothing happened, means battery icon does not have any reflect or when unplug power supply use battery until become completely empty without hibernate or even shut down. Just after restart can detect plug/unplug. This problem occurred (I think) after removing `gnome-shell`.

When power plugged in:

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online 
1
    $ upower -d
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun 31 May 2015 11:54:33 PM IRDT (506 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                Primary
  serial:               05171 2011/07/28
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 01 Jun 2015 12:01:28 AM IRDT (91 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              44.1288 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         45.1008 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45.1008 Wh
    energy-rate:         5.8644 W
    voltage:             12.585 V
    time to full:        9.9 minutes
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 03:30:00 AM IRST (1433100779 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              44.1288 Wh
    energy-full:         45.1008 Wh
    energy-rate:         5.8644 W
    time to full:        9.9 minutes
    percentage:          98%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.1
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

After unplug:

```
$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/AC/online 
0
    $ upower -d
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
  native-path:          AC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 01 Jun 2015 12:07:52 AM IRDT (8 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               Hewlett-Packard
  model:                Primary
  serial:               05171 2011/07/28
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Mon 01 Jun 2015 12:07:54 AM IRDT (6 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              45.0468 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         45.1008 Wh
    energy-full-design:  45.1008 Wh
    energy-rate:         13.23 W
    voltage:             12.266 V
    time to empty:       3.4 hours
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1433101073  100.000 discharging
    1433101072  99.000  charging
  History (rate):
    1433101074  13.230  discharging
    1433101073  15.228  discharging
    1433101072  5.237   charging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thu 01 Jan 1970 03:30:00 AM IRST (1433101080 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              45.0468 Wh
    energy-full:         45.1008 Wh
    energy-rate:         13.23 W
    time to empty:       3.4 hours
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.1
  on-battery:      yes
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

Add `acpi_osi=Linux` to grub and update it, but still have the same problem.

Run `sudo aptitude reinstall gnome-power-manager` but ...

```
$ upower -m
Monitoring activity from the power daemon. Press Ctrl+C to cancel.
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
[00:05:28.228]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0

$ laptop-detect -v
We're a laptop (ACPI batteries found)
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw 
demon                     
    description: Notebook
    product: HP ProBook 4530s (XU015UT#ABA)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: A0001D02
    serial: CNU13539PN
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5336AN sku=XU015UT#ABA uuid=FFB143E6-AD38-E111-B7E7-D484BF0CB0F0
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 167C
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       version: KBC Version 22.24
       serial: PCCAE00QE1FDXJ
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Hewlett-Packard
          physical id: a
          version: 68SRR Ver. F.40
          date: 03/12/2013
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 2496KiB
          capabilities: pci pcmcia upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 0
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 2100MHz
          capacity: 2100MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 4
             slot: Unknown
             size: 3KiB
             capacity: 3KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back instruction
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 3
             slot: Unknown
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back instruction
        *-cache:2
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 2
             slot: Unknown
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 1
          slot: Unknown
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 5
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: EBJ41UF8BCS0-DJ-F
             vendor: Elpida
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0A751FC4
             slot: Bottom-Slot 1(top)
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: Bottom-Slot 2(under)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:32 memory:d4000000-d43fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:31 memory:d4904000-d490400f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:d4909000-d49093ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:33 memory:d4900000-d4903fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 memory:d4800000-d48fffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:3000(size=8192) memory:d0000000-d3ffffff ioport:bfb00000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 memory:d4700000-d47fffff
           *-generic:0
                description: System peripheral
                product: SD/MMC Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:23:00.0
                version: 30
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:d4703000-d47030ff memory:d4710000-d471ffff
           *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
                description: SD Host controller
                product: Standard SD Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:23:00.2
                version: 30
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:d4702000-d47020ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: MS Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:23:00.3
                version: 30
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=jmb38x_ms latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:d4701000-d47010ff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 memory:d4600000-d46fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 01
                serial: 74:de:2b:02:0b:da
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.18.11-031811-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:19 memory:d4600000-d460ffff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:28 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:d4500000-d45fffff ioport:d4400000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 06
                serial: 10:1f:74:e3:50:5a
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:29 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d4404000-d4404fff memory:d4400000-d4403fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:d4908000-d49083ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:30 ioport:5068(size=8) ioport:5074(size=4) ioport:5060(size=8) ioport:5070(size=4) ioport:5040(size=32) memory:d4907000-d49077ff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: TOSHIBA MK3261GS
             vendor: Toshiba
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 0C
             serial: 71Q1F6SPS
             size: 298GiB (320GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=4166d6a8
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 86e540f2-beac-4e58-bd87-1bcadd5e307b
                size: 19GiB
                capacity: 19GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2014-10-02 19:14:26 filesystem=ext4 label=Ubuntu lastmountpoint=/ modified=2015-05-31 10:31:32 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2015-05-31 10:31:32 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /mnt/346A73466A7303C0
                version: 3.1
                serial: c2861a6a-21e0-8644-952f-8ac673f40627
                size: 40GiB
                capacity: 40GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-12-01 04:06:59 filesystem=ntfs label=WIN 8.1 mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux swap volume
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 1
                serial: da3774ef-eb00-49f4-ba84-ed2c7f5d9664
                size: 4973MiB
                capacity: 4973MiB
                capabilities: primary nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                logical name: /media/vahid/Data
                version: 3.1
                serial: 0062ee8d-b73b-2d44-82cd-7550f61da814
                size: 233GiB
                capacity: 233GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2011-12-28 18:31:33 filesystem=ntfs label=Data mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW TS-L633R
             vendor: hp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 0400
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
  *-battery
       product: PR06047
       vendor: 13-42
       physical id: 1
       slot: Primary
       capacity: 47520mWh
       configuration: voltage=10.8V
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth1
       serial: 90:f6:52:49:75:db
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.1.100 link=yes multicast=yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem solved by reinstalling upower and gnome-power-manager.
`sudo apt-get purge upower gnome-power-manager` and `sudo apt-get install  upower gnome-power-manager`

Comment: On Linux Mint 18.2 these steps uninstalled the window manager, cinnamon. I had to `Ctrl-Alt-F1` into a terminal session, then `sudo apt-get install cinnamon; cinnamon --restart` to get the system running again. The AC power recognition is still not working.

Comment: @user207863 Same effect on ubuntu 14.04, I had to reinstall ubuntu-desktop. The AC power recognition is still not working

Comment: I checked, today, and it magically started working. My guess is that a recent kernel upgrade fixed the problem. I'm on distro Linux Mint 18.2, kernel version 4.10.0-35-generic #39~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP.

Comment: still happening in ubuntu 20.04, solution also still works

Comment: BE CAREFUL! This ruined my day. I had to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` to get it back working