# My Ubuntu 16.04 does not recognize power supply plug/unplug instantaneously

Tags: power-management, battery, gnome-power-manager

It takes some time after the change in state for it to actually reflect in the Unity Panel. `upower -m` also has the same delay to update.

I have tried reinstalling upower and gnome-power-manager [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/630882/598439) using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge upower gnome-power-manager  
sudo apt-get install  upower gnome-power-manager
```

Does anyone know to solve this and make it responsive?

**Laptop Model:** Acer Aspire E 15 (E5-573-5108)

Comment: How much time does it take to reflect a power change?

Comment: @heynnema that is also highly inconsistent. Sometimes it reflects in 1-2 seconds and sometimes in takes a lot more.

Comment: Sounds kind of normal to me.

Comment: @heynnema 1-2 seconds is normal indeed. But, usually it take longer time, even a minute at times.

Comment: I can't tell you. Maybe somebody else will chime in.

Comment: @heynnema yeah, I'll wait for that...

Comment: In the mean time, you could always try 16.10 to see if that works better. Even if you just boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD, it should tell you.

Comment: @heynnema sure, I'll try that.