# Why does Ubuntu power management set a battery as the default power supply on a desktop machine?

Tags: system-installation, power-management, battery

I have been evaluating distros for my desktop machine. The machine does not have a battery but during the installation, a nonexistent battery is set as my power supply. And the battery is discharging rapidly.

I am multibooting with Windows 10.

My machine is a mini pc, with 464-bit Intel Atom x5-Z8350 GB memory, 64 GB base storage, 128 GB micro SSD,  and a 500 GB SSD. The CPU is an Intel Cherry Trail Z8350.

Almost all of my experience with Ubuntu has been with the server, running Docker.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot detect power supply plug/unplug on Ubuntu 14.04.2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630479/cannot-detect-power-supply-plug-unplug-on-ubuntu-14-04-2). While the question may be different, the answer may be helpful.

Comment: There are no batteries in my machine. It's not a laptop. I tried the solution from "Cannot detect power supply plug/unplug on Ubuntu 14.04.2". It did not fix my problem

Comment: What is the complete output of `laptop-detect -v`?

Comment: It seems only Debian recognizes the power supply

Comment: I am having this problem too and it is driving me crazy. I have one of these Cherry Trail mini pcs and I want to kill the battery indicator and notifications because I'm trying to use it to run looping presentations and I don't want that @#%&@% low battery notification for my nonexistent battery! Have tried a zillion things myself.

Comment: @user535733 - I have the same CPU, the same problem, and my output is `We're a laptop (non device ACPI batteries found)`